# Skype web control : Call feature is not working

Tags: javascript, html, chat, skype, skypedeveloper

I integrated the Skype web control for our website, chat feature is working very well.

But when I click on the the voice or video call.

[image]

It open a new tab where It try to load the url `https://swc.cdn.skype.com/v/0.80.47/calling-popup.html`

#### Which will give the error 404 (not found)

[image]

I have search the doc and other resourced available but no luck.
any help would be appreciated.

Note: If you know how to hide these icon without CSS. It will also help.

Thanks.

Resources:

- Browser: Chrome (68.0.3440.106)
- SKD url: https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js
- Doc: https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol
- Issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3882

Answer (score 0):

The error you have there has nothing to do with Skype , it just a question of the path to the HTML that is supposed to trigger your link, check path, or if the file is there where the url points to.